# Run a Python script on my website

Tags: python, http, beautifulsoup, web-hosting

I am using `beautifulsoup` to scrape data from websites.

My code works when I run it from PyCharm.

When I run it on my website (like `newser.000webhost.com/new.py`) it does not run.

How can I run my code on my site?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def trade_spider(max_pages):

    page = 1

    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'https://www.geo.tv/category/sports/'+ str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
        plain_text = source_code.text.encode('ascii', 'replace')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')

        for div in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'geo-zoom-effect'}):
            for a in div.findAll('a'):
             title = a.get('title')
             href = a.get('href')
             print title
             print href

            for img in a.findAll('img'):
                src=img.get('src')
                print src

        page+=1

trade_spider(5)
```

Comment: How are you trying to run your script ? You need to be logged in your server or to configure some cgi in order to run python scripts from url ...

Comment: what exactly happens? what does "doesn't run
" mean? Have you done anything that would enable it to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

000webhost is a Webhost that serves HTML,CSS, PHP and MySQL files and is not a Python host.

Digital Ocean is a fairly cheap ($5/month) and reliable VPS if you're looking for a full UNIX environment and host your Python files.

If not familiar or want free I'll recommend [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) or [OpenShift](https://openshift.com)

Comment: You are right. 000webhost was unable to run the script. Thank you very much :)